# Toolbar with multiline title that set to one line on scroll

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I want to create a toolbar that can have more that one line when you access to this screen. But when you start scrolling the content below it has to turn into one line.

So it would be something like a collapsing toolbar but it will show more that one line of the title when is expanded and only one line when it is collapsed.

Here is an image with what I want to make:

[image]

Comment: it's little bit of confusing, can you share some code, or some image of output so it is easy to understand

Comment: @MAYURSANCHETI I added an image. Unfortunately I don't have a code yet since I don't know how to proceed. I tried to do it using a collapsing toolbar but I really don't know how to change the lines limit using it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create two textAppearance styles with multiple lines and single line properties. And set them to `CollapsingToolbarLayout` via

```
app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/textWithMultipleLinesStyle"
app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/textWithSingleLineStyle"
```

Comment: textWithMultipleLinesStyle & textWithSingleLineStyle not found, can you show how this style

Comment: it is an example name.. you must create a style and set maxLines to 1 for singleLine and 2 or more for multiple line style yourself.. Briefly You must create styles yourself

Comment: @NDroidev the problem is that I have a ConstraintLayout inside the toolbar because as you can see in the image I upload there is an image and 2 different textviews (only one of them is multiline when extended)

Comment: Try to implement this code and listen for state changes:  https://gist.github.com/ed-george/b2130d15021764a13d3b

Comment: And maybe you can better try to use MaterialToolBar with title and subTitle with styles as in this answer firstly.